# Pandas, merging two dataframes on multiple columns, and multiplying result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe,df1 that looks something like this:

```
Name Event Factor1
John A     2
John B     3
Ken  A     1.5
....
```

and an additional dataframe,df2 like this:

```
Name Event Factor2
John A     1.2
John B     .5
Ken  A     2
```

I would like to join both of these dataframes on the two columns Name and Event, with the resulting columns factor 1 and 2 multiplied by each other.

```
Name Event FactorResult
John A     2.4
John B     1.5
Ken  A     3
```

What would be the best way to do this? I am unsure on how to join these on two columns. I know I can join and then multiply the two columns, but I'm wondering if there is a better way than merging them first, then multiplying and dropping the unneeded columns?

Comment: In general it's better pandas idiom to move both those columns into a multi-index: `df1.set_index(['Name', 'Event'])`. Then you simply do `df1 * df2` !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas.DataFrame.merge) and them multiply:

```
merged = df1.merge(df2, on=['Name', 'Event'])
merged['ResultFactor'] = merged.Factor1 * merged.Factor2
result = merged.drop(['Factor1', 'Factor2'], axis=1)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
   Name Event  ResultFactor
0  John     A           2.4
1  John     B           1.5
2   Ken     A           3.0
```

Answer (score 11):

If your dataframes are identically labelled, you don't need to merge,

```
(df1.set_index(['Name', 'Event'])['Factor1'] * df2.set_index(['Name', 'Event'])['Factor2']).reset_index(name = 'FactorResult')

    Name    Event   FactorResult
0   John    A       2.4
1   John    B       1.5
2   Ken     A       3.0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df  = pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, on=['Name','Event'], how='inner']
df['FactorResult'] = df['Factor1'] * df['Factor2']
df = df[['Name', 'Event', 'FactorResult']]
```